# Golang Struct an Array of Json objects

Tags: go

I'm a bit confused as to why my method of approach isn't working.
What i'm trying to accomplish is to obtain the ID from the api call that returns the json format. I would then need to subsequently do another call by passing in that id to obtain the values for everything within that call
Below you'll see my method of approach and the rough layout of what i'm playing with.

```
    res, err := http.Get("xyz")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()

    var publications []Publications
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    json.Unmarshal(body, &publications)

    fmt.Println((publications))
```

I currently have a Json array similar to this First api Call

```
[
    {
      "id": 12101,
      "location":"SD",
      "name": "Joe",
      "date": "2022-04-21T00:00:00-04:00",
    },
    {
      "id": 141201,
      "location": "NY",
      "name": "Sky",
      "date": "2022-04-21T00:00:00-04:00",
    },
]
```

Answer (score 3):

This example shows how to parse your first JSON array into a struct.

Play with it on the [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/wpkZBai5clz).

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type payload []entry

type entry struct {
    Id       int       `json:"id"`
    Location string    `json:"location"`
    Name     string    `json:"name"`
    Date     time.Time `json:"date"`
}

func main() {

    str := `
[
    {
      "id": 12101,
      "location":"SD",
      "name": "Joe",
      "date": "2022-04-21T00:00:00-04:00"
    },
    {
      "id": 141201,
      "location": "NY",
      "name": "Sky",
      "date": "2022-04-21T00:00:00-04:00"
    }
]
`

    var publication1 payload
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &publication1)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v\n", err)
    }

    for _, p := range publication1 {
        fmt.Printf("id = %d\n", p.Id)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
id = 12101
id = 141201
```